# PHP mySQL Update row function not working as expected - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

My apologies I know there are several similar questions around but I could not find one referring to mine close enough. I have an edit and update form which is getting the entries of the selected row fetched in which is working fine. However when trying to call the update function it is not working but giving me back various errors depending on how I try to fix it. The current version throws the above error code and more specific is referring to the SQL code which I cannot see anything wrong with:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '(event_name='test', event_description='test', event_cate' at line 2

As per the above the variables are apparently being passed as intended but the event is not being updated. I have tried both passing the event_id as well as not to, the event_id is auto incremental and shall not be updated, additionally there is a user_id_fk which I suppose would not be relevant here. My createevent function is pretty much the same and working. Do I need to pass an array instead in order to update an exisiting row?

My on page php:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
    $eventid=($_POST['eventid']);
    $eventname=strip_tags($_POST['eventname']);
    $eventdescription=strip_tags($_POST['eventdescription']);
    $eventcategory=strip_tags($_POST['eventcategory']);
    $eventdate = $_POST["eventdate"];
    $sqlDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($eventdate));
    $eventvenue=strip_tags($_POST['eventvenue']);
    $eventlocation=strip_tags($_POST['eventlocation']);


    if($eventname=="") {
      $error[] = "provide eventname !";
    }  
    if($eventcategory=="") {
      $error[] = "provide eventcategory !";
    }
    if($eventdescription=="") {
      $error[] = "provide eventdescription !"; 
    }
    if($eventlocation=="") {
      $error[] = "provide eventlocation !";
    }
    else if($eventdate=="") {
      $error[] = "provide a date !";
    }
    else if($eventvenue=="") {
      $error[] = "provide eventvenue !";
    }


   else
    {

        if($event->updateevent($eventid,$eventname,$eventdescription,$eventcategory,$eventdate,$eventvenue,$eventlocation)) 
            {
                $event->redirect('members.php');
                echo "Your event has been successfully updated.";
            }

    }

    }
```

The referred html form:

```
    <div id="updateevent">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' name="eventid" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>">
        <label>Event title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventname" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_name']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Description: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventdescription" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_description']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Category: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventcategory" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_category']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Venue: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventvenue" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_venue']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Event date: </label>
        <input type="date" name="eventdate" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_date']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Event location: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventlocation" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_location']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update" /></form>
    </form>
    </div>
```

The called function in my events.php class:

```
public function updateevent($event_id,$event_name,$event_description,$event_category,$event_date,$event_venue,$event_location)
{
   try
   {

       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE events 
                                    SET event_name=:eventname, //UPDATED
                                        event_description=:eventdescription,
                                        event_category=:eventcategory,
                                        event_date=:sqldate,
                                        event_venue=:eventvenue,
                                        event_location=:eventlocation
                                    WHERE event_id=:eventid");

       $stmt->bindparam(":eventid", $event_id);
       $stmt->bindparam(":eventname", $event_name);
       $stmt->bindparam(":eventdescription", $event_description);
       $stmt->bindparam(":eventcategory", $event_category);
       $stmt->bindparam(":sqldate", $event_date);
       $stmt->bindparam(":eventvenue", $event_venue);
       $stmt->bindparam(":eventlocation", $event_location);

       $stmt->execute(); 

       return $stmt; 
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }    
}
```

Thanks for any help with this

**

> UPDATE: Upon removing the brackets within the UPDATE statement I get
>   not error back but the row still is not updating.

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `(` and `)`:

```
UPDATE events 
                                    SET event_name=:eventname,
                                        event_description=:eventdescription,
                                        event_category=:eventcategory,
                                        event_date=:sqldate,
                                        event_venue=:eventvenue,
                                        event_location=:eventlocation
                                    WHERE event_id=:eventid
```

SET has no `(` and `)`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks @AndrewShmig, now it does not throw an error at all but is not updating the row either. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have any rows that match `UPDATE` + `WHERE` clause? Show us the `SELECT` results.

Comment: When the events for a logged in user are being fetched I use $stmt = $event->runQuery("SELECT event_id, event_name, event_description, event_category, event_venue, event_location FROM events WHERE user_id_fk=$userid");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
This is giving the correct result- user_id_fk is hereby referring to userid which is taken from the login session value. Runquery is also predefined in the class file:

 public function runQuery($sql)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt;
 }

Comment: @Yo_42, in your `UPDATE` clause you are using an `event_id` field, but in your `SELECT` - some other one... we need to know / check if the `event_id = :eventid` really exists before `UPDATE` is performed. Try selecting data before an update and see if there is any result that match `event_id = :eventid`.

Comment: when doing so I get:
Notice: Undefined index: event_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\php\editevent.php on line 133
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens // This should be because I unbound the remaining variable in the function.

Line 133 is referring to the form:
<input type='hidden' name="eventid" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>">

Could the problem be caused by the input type being hidden?

Comment: you pushed me to the right direction here, essentially all parameters were passed from the events listing per user page except for the event_id which was therefore empty. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `set` clause doesn't have parenthesis. Just remove them and you should be OK:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE events 
                             SET event_name=:eventname,
                                 event_description=:eventdescription,
                                 event_category=:eventcategory,
                                 event_date=:sqldate,
                                 event_venue=:eventvenue,
                                 event_location=:eventlocation
                             WHERE event_id=:eventid");
```

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik, now it does not throw an error at all but is not updating the row either. Any ideas?